# Connect TableView columns to the HashMap values

Tags: java, javafx, hashmap, tableview

I'm writing a simple crud-redactor, and there is a problem I stuck on:

I have a class:

```
public class Note {
    List<String> columnNames;
    HashMap<String, SimpleStringProperty> items;
}
```

which I need to somehow connect with a `TableView` via `setCellValueFactory`.
For example I have 3 values in HashMap with keys `"id"`, `"name"` and `"age"`. So I want to have 3 columns in `TableView` which are connected with this `HashMap` and will represent its values after wrapping an array of Notes into `ObservableList` and using `TableView` method `setItems()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use value factories returning the value in the map for a given key, e.g.

```
final String key = "id";
TableColumn<Note, String> column = new TableColumn<>("ID");
column.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().items.get(key));
```

In case you need to use the keys from `columnNames` you could get the property based on the index instead, e.g.

```
final String index = 1;
TableColumn<Note, String> column = new TableColumn<>("1");
column.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().columnNames.size() <= index ?
                                    null
                                  : cd.getValue().items.get(cd.getValue().columnNames.get(index)));
```

Note that depending on the package used you may need to add getters to the `Note` class.

---

You could also create non-existing properties "on the fly", by using `Map.computeIfAbsent` instead of `get`, if that is the desired behaviour:

```
items.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new SimpleStringProperty())
```