# JavaFX - HashMap into TableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a `class` that contains a `String` and a `HashMap`. I want to put the `string` value into the first column, and dynamically create columns to fit the `HashMap` where its keys would be column names, and its values rows.

So, basically, I have the same issue as here:

[Connect TableView columns to the HashMap values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506108/connect-tableview-columns-to-the-hashmap-values)

However, after trying the answer provided in that question, I confronted an exception/warning, and every time I tried to go around it, it would still pop, and quite frankly I'm kinda losing it. Further details in code.

**Student Class**

```
Class Mark {
    private String studentName;
    private HashMap<String, SimpleDoubleProperty> marks;
    // Getters and setters and whatnot.
```

**Related code in controller Class**

```
....
@FXML
TableView<Mark> marksTable;
....

    private void loadMarksTable(ObservableList<Mark> marks) {
        marksTable.setItems(marks);
        marksTable.setVisible(true);

        TableColumn<Mark, String> column = new TableColumn<Mark, String>("student name");
        column.setCellValueFactory(cd -> new SimpleStringProperty(cd.getValue().getStudentName()));
        marksTable.getColumns().add(column);

        for (Entry<String, SimpleDoubleProperty> entry: marks.get(0).getMarks().entrySet()) {

            // Instead of Number I tried a lot of things, including Double and SimpleDoubleProperty
            TableColumn<Mark, Number> col = new TableColumn<Mark, Number>(entry.getKey()); 

            /*
             * Warning here (underlines code starting from cd ->) : type mismatch: cannot convert from SimpleDoubleProperty  to ObservableValue<String>
             */
            col.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().getMarks().get(entry.getKey()));
            marksTable.getColumns().add(col);
}
```

Before looping to add columns I tried to have a method that would a column, but a `NullPointerException` would appear when I try to load the table:

**Add Column method**

```
private void addColumn(String keyName) {
    TableColumn<Mark, Double> column = new TableColumn<Mark, Double>(keyName);
    column.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().getMarks().get(keyName).asObject()); // <- NullPointerException. Also tried without .asObject()
    marksTable.getColumns().add(column);
```

A detailed explanation on how this works would be much appreciated.

Comment: The warning shouldn't happen with the declared types. (In particular `ObservableValue<String>` should not be involved as target type unless the second type parameter of the column is `String`.) Probably your IDE didn't refresh. Try the clean & rebuild functionality of the IDE. As for the `NullPointerException`: either `getMarks()` or `getMarks().get(name)` returns `null`, it that's the line throwing the exception; do all maps contain the same keys? Where is `name` coming from?

Comment: @fabian `name` was a typo. It should be `keyName` - I edited accordingly. I tried cleaning and rebuilding and it didn't work. I took it a step further and imported the whole project into NetBeans and surprisingly that worked. I uninstalled eclipse and reinstalled it and downloaded all plugins, then imported the project again, and it worked. So a bug in eclipse was causing that? strange. Maybe it's one of the imported libraries? Anyway, thank you for your help, I'll post the answer soon.